# How to create a grid of elements using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

First off I'm relatively new to all of this so please excuse me if this is a simple question or if I'm not even asking it correctly :).

I'm trying to create a grid of divs based on a user selection. The gird sizes I am attempting to create are 4x4, 6x6, 8x8.

I set up a nested for loop. My thought was it would create one row with 6 columns and then repeated the process to create 5 more rows with associated columns.

What ends up happening is all the columns end up as children to the first row. I assume it is because the selector $("#row).append is finding the first match and putting everything there.

*This is what I have so far, I will finish out the switch statement once i get the first case working*

I think the issue is with $("#row").append - its finding the first div each time it loops.

```
$("input").click(function(){
  var gameSize = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#cardspace").empty();   ///3 radios to set size of grid, clear if they changed selection
 
  switch (gameSize) {
    case "6x6":
       
        for(var l = 0; l<6; l++) {

            $("#cardspace").append("<div class=row></div>");
                           
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            $("#row").append("<div class=gamecard></div>"); 
            }
        }
            $("#cardspace").addClass("six-six");
            $(".gamecard").addClass("col-sm");

        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is to give only a single value to the radio buttons like 4,6,8 and use this value to create the grid. It will make your code more dynamic and save you to write the same switch code repeatedly.

Here is a working example:

```js
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
  var gameSize = $(this).val();
  $("#cardspace").empty();
  for (var l = 0; l < gameSize; l++) {
    var childHtml = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < gameSize; i++) {
      childHtml += "<div class='gamecard col-sm'>"+l+"</div>";
    }
    $("#cardspace").append("<div class='row' style='width:" + ((100 / gameSize) - 1) + "%' >" + childHtml + "</div>");
  }
});
```

```css
#cardspace .row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}

#cardspace .row .gamecard {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="4x4" value="4">
<label for="4x4">4x4</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="6x6" value="6">
<label for="6x6">6x6</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="8x8" value="8">
<label for="8x8">8x8</label><br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="cardspace"></div>
```

Note: Since I am not a designer, I have added very basic CSS code to just show you what I have done. Please take care of CSS at your end.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling I had to concatenate but I couldn't figure it out.  Thanks for the tip on setting value for the radios! I just removed the width portion and let bootstrap handle the sizing and it works perfect!